# Can I update the firebase database rules into my machine?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

Is there a way to "deploy backwards", meaning updating the database rules file that I have on my machine with the changes that were already made online, using the firebase CLI?

I know it's possible to run `firebase init database` but it requires to confirm stuff twice (using `/force` didn't work).

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase CLI doesn't have a command to pull the rules of the Firebase Realtime Database as far as I know.

You **can** get the rules via the REST API of the Realtime Database though, as shown in the documentation on [Retrieving Firebase Realtime Database Rules via the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/app-management#retrieving-firebase-realtime-database-rules). With CURL that's look like this:

```
curl 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules.json?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>'
```

Alternatively, you can copy the riles from the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/_/rules) and then paste them into your local file.